# P values of coefficients from ClusterBootstrap GLMs

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am using the following data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ovl8oQnIi_uApVCo93BN_UOUY3F1YoKw/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117026321594556045652&rtpof=true&sd=true

and the `ClusterBootstrap` package to perform hierarchical clustering to compare my treatments and sexes.

I ran the following:

```r
library(ClusterBootstrap)
set.seed(1)
model_3 <- clusbootglm(Area ~ Treatment*Sex, data = area_test, 
    clusterid = Animal_Number, family = gaussian, B = 5000, 
    confint.level = 0.95, n.cores = 1)
summary(model_3)
```

which returned the following output:

```r
Call:
clusbootglm(model = Area ~ Treatment * Sex, data = area_test, 
    clusterid = Animal_Number, family = gaussian, B = 5000, 
    confint.level = 0.95, n.cores = 1)

                    Estimate Std.error    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
(Intercept)       507.695127  32.96057  457.73586 598.534695
TreatmentMOR      -49.651210  33.95824 -134.64310   3.637668
SexF               -4.848862  61.37184 -139.97994 103.182006
TreatmentMOR:SexF  24.322561  65.11656  -91.28945 158.972550
---
95% confidence interval using bias corrected and accelerated cluster bootstrap intervals
There were 59 bootstrap samples which returned at least one NA
```

This is great, but I wondered how to get the p values of the estimates, similar to what is provided in the normal glm output.

Would following the instructions posted here

https://www.statology.org/interpret-prz-logistic-regression-output-r/

work for this type of data? It essentially calculates a z value and then converts it to a two tailed p value.

By doing that, I got a p value for TreatmentMOR of 0.14.

```r
z_value_mor <- abs(-49.651210/33.95824)
p_value_mor <- 2*(1-pnorm(z_value_mor))
```

That seems approximately correct looking at the 95% confidence intervals, but I wanted to confirm before doing it on all my data.

Comment: @VonC has previously helped me and confirmed that I could ping them for future help.